# Electric field and magnetic field question here?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

Are the energy of the electric field and the energy of the magnetic field concentrated on their sources OR are they scattered in the environment where the fields arent zero? Can you base your answer on a formula so I can understand it better?

Comment: This page is a good starting place for you: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html

Comment: What do you mean by "concentrated on their sources"? As in on the surface (for, say, a charged sphere)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulae for the Electric and Magnetic field energy densities are as follows:

$$D_E = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2$$ and $$ D_B = \frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2 $$These can be obtained from Maxwell's equations, with some algebra.
If you want to know the energy stored in some volume, integrate these equations within said volume.

So first off you see that, in order for there to be energy stored in an electric/magnetic field, you **need** to have a non-zero field.

Now, what does it mean to have energy **stored** in a field? this is how I see it:

If you have an electric/magnetic field, then it means that something has been done to create it, e.g. gathering charges into a sphere or flowing a current in a solenoid.
The energy that you put into creating the field is now stored into it. In creating a charged sphere, for example, you might have had to bring charges together, therefore doing work against the electric repulsion between them. In flowing a steady current through a solenoid, you might have encountered an induced current that was trying to keep the magnetic flux constant (by Faraday's law).

At the sources, the field is usually infinite.
This is due to the $\frac{1}{r^2}$ dependence of the electric field (or of the magnetic field, in the [Biot-Savart law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law)) which makes them blow up.

This of course causes problems in calculating the energy stored when you have to integrate up to 0.
Usually, when dealing with a charged sphere or any 3-D object, the field inside goes as $\propto r$ (from Gauss's law) so it's fine.
HOWEVER, in the case of a point particle, then the integral blows up to infinity.
And this is a problem. Quite a famous one.
I think the solution is that you cannot consider the electron as a point particle and for very small distances you need to include some QM or QFT effects.

Comment: Harold, quantum theory has the same problem with infinities, only more complicated. One solution is to discard Poynting expressions for point particles: the Poynting theorem cannot be derived from Maxwell's equations if the charge density $\rho$ and current density $\mathbf j$ are delta distributions.

Comment: so what do you do? You approximate the particle as having some spatial distribution?

Comment: No, point particles are fine. Just the Poynting theorem does not apply to them.

Comment: so what do you do? What other theorems can we use?

Comment: For point particle we can use Lorentz formula for the force acting on it: $\mathbf F_{-a} = d\mathbf p_a/dt = q_a \mathbf E_0(\mathbf r_a) + q_a \frac{\mathbf v_a}{c} \times \mathbf B_0(\mathbf r_a)$. The field $\mathbf E_0,\mathbf B_0$ is external field - sum of fields due to other particles and possibly background field with no sources. If we assume the Maxwell equations are valid for all these fields, we can derive energy conservation theorem analogous to the Poynting theorem, and momentum conservation theorem, valid even for point particles.

Comment: The idea is explained also in papers J. Frenkel, Zur Elektrodynamik punktf¨ ormiger Elektronen, Zeits. f. Phys., 32, (1925), p. 518-534.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01331692 and J. A. Wheeler, R. P. Feynman, Classical Electrodynamics in Terms of Direct
Interparticle Interaction, Rev. Mod. Phys., 21, 3, (1949), p. 425-433.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.21.425 . However, they also assume half-retarded, half-advanced fields, which is not necessary to solve the above problem.